# "double Cannot be Dereferenced" toString() - does this alternative form without errors mean the same thing?

Tags: java, netbeans, return, double, tostring

In the following snippet of code the int returns properly, but when I try doing the same thing with a double NetBeans 8.0.2 complains that "double Cannot be Dereferenced"

The non-commented out variables work. The commented out variables are double and do not work.

```
@Override
public String toString() 
{
    return "[" + getAccountNumber() + "], " +
            super.toString() + ", " +
            owner.toString() 
          // Error: "Double Cannot be Dereferenced" why?

          //  + ", " + currentBalance.toString()
          //  + ", " + interestRate.toString()
            ;
}
```

When I rewrite it like this NetBeans doesn't give me an error, but is this effectively the same thing for a double?

```
@Override
public String toString() 
{
    return "[" + getAccountNumber() + "], " +
            super.toString() + ", " +
            owner.toString() 
          // Error: "Double Cannot be Dereferenced"

          //  + ", " + currentBalance.toString()
          //  + ", " + interestRate.toString()

          // The following seems to work instead:

            + ", " + Double.toString(currentBalance)
            + ", " + Double.toString(interestRate)
            ;
}
```

If so, great. No errors. If not, what can I do to make sure that the value of a double returns to the String just as an int would?

**UPDATE**:
From the answers I received, it looks like second approach I used works, but the following works just as well:

```
 @Override
public String toString() 
{
    return "[" + getAccountNumber() + "], " +
    super.toString() + ", " +
    owner + ", " +
    currentBalance + ", " +
    interestRate;
}
```

Comment: Try String.valueOf(your_double_variable) and same in opposite-direction Double.valueOf(your_String_variable). Ofcourse the values should be convertible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet it's not saying "Double Cannot be Dereferenced"; it's most likely saying "`double` Cannot be Dereferenced". (Note the difference between `Double`, which means the wrapper class `java.lang.Double`, and the primitive type `double`).

You didn't show what `currentBalance` is, but it is probably a variable of the primitive type `double`. You cannot call methods on primitive types, that's why you get the error message.

You do not need to explicitly call `toString()` on variables when you do string concatenation. Try this instead:

```
@Override
public String toString() 
{
    return "[" + getAccountNumber() + "], " +
        super.toString() + ", " +
        owner + ", " +
        currentBalance + ", " +
        interestRate;
}
```

Comment: currentBalance is, as I said, a double variable. Unfortunately your solution isn't completely accurate. Netbeans says ". expected" on super, but this slight modification combined with your approach works perfectly. super.toString()

Comment: @Elliander Yes, sorry, that was a small mistake, you indeed have to use `super.toString()` instead of just `super`. Fixed in my answer above.

Answer (score 3):

`Primitive types` do not have methods, they are not `objects`. You cannot invoke methods on `primitives`.

The error you are getting is:

```
double cannot be dereferenced
```

and not:

```
Double cannot be dereferenced
```

`double` is a `primitive`, `Double` is wrapper for the primitive `double`, it is an `Object`.

You cannot call methods on `double` but you can on `Double`.

So `Double.toString(currentBalance)` is correct. `currentBalance.toString()` is not.

Also you said: *"The non-commented out variables are int and work"*

Actually, it will not work if its `int` for the same reason.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo on the question subject. Thanks for the clarification, also, I didn't realize it, but you are right about the int as well. Even though I was using an int in those classes, it looks like I was using Customer type as well. I'll edit the question accordingly.